# How to add arguments to the Splinter Browser() command?

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I'd like to automate the following Linux shell command:

```
google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome
```

using `splinter` (or `selenium`), but I cannot find documentation/examples that explain how to pass arguments and values to the `Browser` command.

The following (wrong) code shows what I tried:

```
"""
google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome
"""

from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("password-store", "basic")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("user-data-dir", "/tmp/chrome")
browser = Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options)
```

Can you help with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done:

```
from splinter import Browser
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver

def prepare_special_chrome():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome")
    browser = Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options)
    browser.visit('https://machine.local/#/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prepare_special_chrome()
```